# Django ModelAdmin: how to ask password using two secret fields?

Tags: django

This is my custom user model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_company')
```

Since there is a foreign key field, I have created a custom ModelAdmin:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('groups', 'user_permissions', 'date_joined')
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'company')
```

Otherwise it works fine, but there is only one, clear-text password field shown. How can I modify it so that Django Admin would ask the password using the default two field approach?

Comment: You should inherit from the UserAdmin class rather than the base ModelAdmin, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin).

Comment: @DanielRoseman If I do that, then Django Admin will first ask for username and password only, and when saving them it complains that required field 'company' is missing.

Comment: You should make that null=True, blank=True then. The model with Users in the admin is to enter just the basic sign-up information to start with, then add the rest afterwards.

Comment: Ok, I could also consider filling default values in save method.